# How to connect Pyspark with Cassandra

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra

So I am trying to connect PySpark with Cassandra, but I could figure how, and I have already tried a lot of things I found in Stack Overflow and other pages.
I get the next error `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o75.load.`.

I start pyspark with this command 
`pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.0`

And I am using:

- Python 2.75
- Spark 2.4.0
- Cloudera 6.2.0

Cassandra has username, password and 3 ips i.e. "127.0 0.1,127.0 0.2,127.0 0.1"

I am using the next snippet to try to connect with cassandra:

```
data_frame = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .option("spark.cassandra.connection.host",host_casandra)\
    .option("spark.cassandra.auth.username", username_cassandra) \
    .option("spark.cassandra.auth.password", password_cassandra) \
    .options(table=table_casandra, keyspace=keyspace_cassandra).load()
```

The entire error is the next:< /br>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o73.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource$.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource$.<clinit>(DefaultSource.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:317)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudera Hadoop [is based on the Hadoop 3.0](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/release-notes/topics/rg_cdh_62_packaging.html) that uses `commons-configuration2` library instead of `commons-configuration` that is used by Spark Cassandra Connector. You can start your `pyspark` with following:

```
pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.0,commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.10
```

to explicitly add `commons-configuration`.

Or even better, use [assembly version of spark cassandra connector](http://libraryDependencies%20+=) (additional benefit - it has [much more functionality](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all) compared to version 2.4.0):

```
pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.11:2.5.1
```